# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got CHAR 00932. 00000

Tags: database, oracle

Getting error while running below query in Oracle where notes(Table Name) have column1 datatype-Clob & Column2 datatype  VARCHAR2(4000).Could you please help me regarding that issue. Thanks

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CLOB got CHAR
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

```
SELECT 
 CASE
      WHEN notes.column1 IS NOT NULL
      THEN ''
        ||  notes.column1 
        || ' '
      WHEN notes.Column2 IS NOT NULL
      THEN ''
         || TO_CHAR(notes.Column2)
        || ' '
    END TEST
  FROM notes
```

Comment: In first then you return a clob in second a char. You have to return in call cases the same data type

Comment: But if the second column2 is not clob datatype what should i do I dont want to change the datatype of colmn2

Comment: convert one of  the values

Comment: Could you just please provide me sample for that.Thanks for reply

Comment: Hint: there is such a thing as [`to_clob`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions202.htm#SQLRF06131). Also, maybe [`COALESCE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) would suit your needs better. Also, I'm not sure why you're appending a null before the columns - in Oracle, there is no such thing as the empty string - instead, it gets treated as null.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working :) :)